# GWT DateTimeFormat parsing to feed DateBox

Tags: java, gwt

I need to parse date like **"Wed Apr 30 00:00:00 CEST 2014"** to **"dd/mm/yyyy"** format.

I already found the solution, but java.text.DateFormat is needed, and I can't use it on GWT client side. I need this date parsed to feed GWT DateBox.

Anyone has a clue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `DateTimeFormat` instead.

This should do it:

```
DateTimeFormat inputFormat = DateTimeFormat.getFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy");
DateTimeFormat outputFormat= DateTimeFormat.getFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");

outputFormat.format(inputFormat.parse("Wed Apr 30 00:00:00 CEST 2014"));
```

Comment: @kklys Then the format isn't correct. Make sure to use the correct pattern.

Comment: You mean "EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy"?

Comment: @kklys Yes. I'm not 100% sure that's the correct pattern

Comment: @kklys `CEST` seems to be the problem. Works fine with `GMT`.

Comment: yep. I tried to use `z`-`zzzz` and `Z`-`ZZZZ` patterns for time zone but no luck here with `CEST`. date is from external DB, so I have deal with data as it is. any ideas how to work this out?

Comment: @kklys You should post a bug report. GWT should be able to handle this.

Comment: It came out, that data in our database has wrong format, and the correct one is much more simple, so problem solved in my case :) But it should by possible to parse this format anyway. If I find the solution I will post it here. Thanks for your time!

Comment: @kklys No problem! If you can't find another solution, please consider accepting my answer.